# Equivalence Of Definitions Of Connectedness

Tags: metric-spaces, connectedness

In Rudin's Analysis the definition of connectedness is given as follows:
$$$$A subset $A$ of a metric space $X$ is said to be connected if $A$ cannot be written as $$A= C \cup D$$ where $C$ and $D$ are separated sets.
$$$$But in Apostol's Analysis the definition of connectedness is given as :
$$$$A metric space $X$ is said to be connected if it can not be written as $$X =A \cup B$$ where $A$ and $B$ are non empty disjoint open sets of $X$
$$$$I want to know that one definition is for subsets of metric spaces while the other is for metric spaces. Are these two definitions same or do they have different meaning.

Answer (score 2):

They are equivalent for topological spaces, not just for metric spaces. If $X=A\cup B$, where $A$ and $B$ are non-empty disjoint open sets, then $A$ and $B$ are also closed, since each is the complement of an open set, so

$$A\cap\operatorname{cl}B=A\cap B=\varnothing=A\cap B=(\operatorname{cl}A)\cap B\,,$$

i.e., $A$ and $B$ are separated. Conversely, if $A$ and $B$ are separated, then $A\cap\operatorname{cl}B=\varnothing$, so $B\subseteq\operatorname{cl}B\subseteq X\setminus A=B$, and hence $\operatorname{cl}B=B$. Thus, $B$ is closed, and $A$ is therefore open. A similarly argument shows that $B$ is open.

The first definition is more convenient for subsets, but there is still a kind of equivalence: $C$ and $D$ are separated sets in $X$ if and only if they are **relatively** open subsets of $A$; they need not, however, be open in $X$ (and generally are not).

Comment: Why $A$ and $B$ are also closed sets?? And what is $X$ is not a full space?

Comment: @user728159: The complement of an open set is always closed. Indeed, that is often taken as the definition of a closed set. And it is **given** that $X$ is the whole space.

Comment: But what if $X$ is not a full space??

Comment: @user728159: I have no idea what you mean by a ‘full’ space; that is not any kind of standard terminology. A space is a space. Here $X$ is the space in which we’re working.